# Open active/current submenu in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used the menu from this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/22ZyM/3/) on my page.

```
$("#vertical-menu h3").click(function () {
//slide up all the link lists
$("#vertical-menu ul ul").slideUp();
$('.plus',this).html('+');
//slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next().slideDown();
    //$(this).remove("span").append('<span class="minus">-</span>');
    $('.plus').html('+');
    $('.plus',this).html('-');
}
```

Whenever I go into a new sub-page (e.g. Tasks > Today's tasks) it expands the 'Dashboard' part of the menu, because it is set as active. But I want it to be the 'Tasks' part that is expanded, because 'Today's tasks' is a child to Tasks.

How do I change this?

I want it to change the parent li's (Tasks) class to active - and remove the class from another parent li (Dashboard) etc. 
So that whenever I am on a subsite the menu will expand this part of the menu.

I have tried all sorts of URL comparisons that adds class to parents, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Paste all of your js code in this. you pasted only the click handler

Comment: That's because I never found a solution that worked. I tried something like this one: 

    `$(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $("#vertical-menu ul li a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});`

Comment: Or this one: 
`$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#vertical-menu ul ul').find('li').click(function () {
            //removing the previous selected menu state
            $('#vertical-menu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
            //adding the state for this parent menu
            $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
        });
    });`